# Isset not equals on multiple variables

Tags: php

I have a problem using the following code.

```
$test1 = "test1";
$test2 = "test2";

if (!isset($test1) || (!isset($test2))) {

echo "Neither exists";

} else {

echo "One or both exist";

}
```

It works if both exists or none exists but fails if one of the variables exists.

Searched the net but can't find a working solution.

Thanks,

John

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the isset, check whatever the variables exist, or are not null?

Comment: If you want to check that *neither* variable is set, then you want `&&`, not `||`

Comment: Yes, it's more like _either_ than _neither_

Comment: You question made me think and in doing so looks like I've fixed the issue with if (!isset($test1) && (!isset($test2)))

Answer (score 0):

```
$test1 = "test1";
$test2 = "test2";

if (isset($test1) || isset($test2)) {
  echo "one or more is set";
}else{
    echo "none is set";
}
```

This will check if one of the both variables exists. This means they are defined, and are `not null`